# Session layer vs Transport layer

Tags: osi

It seems both do the same thing (or establishing a session between two hosts differs from establishing a connection between two?) So what exactly is the difference here that make us consider them as two separate layers?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I usually explain it is to consider a concrete example of two browsers on a single computer, connected to the same website and logged in as different users.

- There are any number of **transport connections** as the web pages load pages and images.
- There are two **sessions**, normally identified with cookies or whatever.

As Zac says, the sessions are pretty much in the web browser and server, not anywhere else.  The OSI model is to help describe things, not mandate how they're implemented.

Answer (score 4):

In the Internet world, the OSI layers are not strictly followed.

Especially the session layer isn't implemented in the OS stack but (more or less) inside the application (or in a framework). For HTTP, think of session cookies or a session URL parameter - an HTTP client session can consist of a large number of TCP connections. For FTP, the 'session' is the control connection that can spawn data connections, and so on.

Comment: Are there any layers that are (*have to be present*) strictly followed? for instance, I don't see how the network could work without Transport Layer (TCP/UDP), as well as, I can't see how Application Layer can be omitted.. browsers (or any other networking apps) need to use their-level (app-level) protocols, which belong to Transport Layer. I'm just trying to deepen and brush up my years ago learnt networking basics.. I hope I made my question clear - which layers are the must to be implemented. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need layering at all, you can bunch everything together. What you do need though is some way to physically move data, synchronize bits and bytes (physical layer), and the data interpretation in the application layer. Multiplexing a link for various purposes requires some kind of framing and marking though (data link layer). Addressing multiple nodes on-link requires addressing (also data link layer), and so on.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you're contradicting yourself with "you don't need layering at all" and enumerating, at least, "physical" and "data" layers. I'm someone who understands logically/conceptually imaginable/representable scenarios. So, there definitely has to be some logical separation of concerns.. right? when you connect to host with `ncat`, you don't send electrical signals, directly.. rather a TCP Segment is assembled, then it gets down to IP frames (at least, that's how I remember), and etc. So, I want to understand each layer of data transposition, in details.

Comment: Basically, I want to drill down to the very clear image, what exactly happens, where (at which layer) and how (what are the data representations). For instance, when we get to `www.google.com`, 1) browser assembles HTTP message (that is an Application Layer, and that HAS to be existing.. something needs to take UI action and translate it to the programmable protocol); 2) then that HTTP message is broken down into TCP segments (again, I may not be exact.. but that's what I remember).. and etc. So, I want to learn 1) what are the protocols at each layer; 2) how they represent data; and..

Comment: 3) how to manipulate data at each layer (create raw TCP segments, IP frames, etc.).
One example would be the scenario, if I want to write a plain text/bits/bytes and send that as TCP segment.. or IP frame.. basically - I want to understand each layer, their responsibility, their protocols and data representation. I apologise for a bit large text.. I just wanted to clarify my question(s). Thank you, again.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I meant "you don't need *proper layering* but you'll need at least these functions, regardless of how you organize things" and referred to where the functions usually reside. Layering is about modularity and you don't necessarily need that. The rest is a whole new bunch of questions that are not suitable as comments, sorry. You should check out previous questions about layering, there's really a lot here already.

Answer (score 1):

Well, The **Transport Layer** is responsible for giving services to the application
layer: 
to get a message from an application program running on the source host and
deliver it to the corresponding application program on the destination host by creating a **logical connection**.

But the **Session Layer** is more about the session **(logical connection) management** capabilities between hosts. For example, if some host needs a password verification for access and if credentials are provided then for that session password verification does not happen again.

This layer can assist in synchronization, dialog control, and critical operation management (e.g., an online bank transaction).
and If some more functionalities in the session layer are needed for
a particular application, they can be included in the development of that piece of software.